# $\mathbb{Q}$ with topology from $\mathbb{R}$ is not locally compact, but all discrete spaces are

Tags: general-topology

Wikipedia claims that all discrete topological spaces are locally compact but that $\mathbb{Q}$ isn't when endowed with the topology of $\mathbb{R}$.

I don't know if I understand those examples right, at the first sight it seems like a contradiction.

Is the following right:

- If we say "discrete space" we mean "discrete space with discrete topology".
- In the discrete topology every point set is an open set.
- A point set is always compact.
- If $\mathbb{Q}$ is endowed with the topology of $\mathbb{R}$ only $\emptyset$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ are open.

Comment: What is a "point set"?

Comment: Your last point is wrong. Any set of the form $(a, b)\cap\mathbb{Q} = \{x \in \mathbb{Q} \mid a < x < b\}$ is open.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese: ok, and now why isn't $(a, b) \cap \mathbb{Q}$ compact? Especially if $a, b$ aren't rational?

Comment: Consider the cover $\{(\frac{1}{n}, 1)\cap\mathbb{Q} \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ of $(0, 1)\cap\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: very well, that is convincing, I am completely clueless about topology :-D

Answer (score 2):

$\mathbb Q$ is not a discrete space because points are not open.  If you intersect an open set in $\mathbb R$ with $\mathbb Q$ you can never get a single point.  Thus $\mathbb Q$ is not discrete.